# Using javascript, button click triggers enter click inside textarea

Tags: javascript, html

how can I create a button that when clicked, it simulates ENTER as if it were physically pressed on the keyboard.

In other words, this button when clicked simulates the ENTER button inside the text area, where text is being written.

For instance, after the button is clicked,

> **Original text area text:**
>
> XXX XXX XXX

Becomes

> **New text area text:**
>
> XXX XXX XXX
>
> *New line*

All of this is simulated via a button click.

Let's assume the text area has an ID of #QR

Strictly javascript, no jquery

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please share what you've tried so far?

Comment: It is likely not a correct duplicate. You perhaps want `<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("QR").value+='\n';">Enter</button>`

Comment: Unfortunately  I didn't know where to begin

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy though. All you have to do is add an event listener on the button like so:

**HTML Code:**

```
<textarea id="text_area"></textarea>
<button type="button" id="new_line">Click Me!</button>
```

**JS Code**

```
var textarea = document.getElementById("text_area"),
    myBtn    = document.getElementById("new_line");

myBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    textarea.value += "\r\n";
    textarea.focus(); // This is optional, if you want the user to go back into the textarea. This will be good then :)

}, false);
```

Note that i have declared the variables outside of the function such that on each button click, you don't have to jump into the DOM to look for the textarea over & over again.

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<textarea id="txtArea"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="clickOn()">
```

js

```
<script>
function clickOn() 
{
 document.getElementById("txtArea").value = document.getElementById("txtArea").value + "\n*";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is great in the sense that clicking the button adds a new line, but is it possible mimic the actual Keypress of the ENTER button?

Comment: yes possible to call for function clickOn() from place you just want